# how to send HTTP post request and json get values back in php and swift

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode10

i want to post ID by json url to db but couldn't post the parameter to db so the server get all data from db

i tried to post ID  to mysql to return the value back from db using php 
the json http is working fine in browser  but by swift not sending the parameter and get no values from database

for example
i send  ID 
in php the query will bring the emolyee name based on the ID i send
in xcode out put there are no data

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    data_request("http://mallsruh.com/mydata/test.php")
}



func data_request(_ url:String)
{
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let paramString = "ID=1"
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data as NSData?, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        {
            print(dataString)
        }
    }


    task.resume
```

in php file

```
     $numQue=$_GET["ID"];

    $return_arr = array();

   // Check connection
   if (!$conn) {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }

$selectation = "SELECT * FROM people where ID='$numQue'  ";

$selectationQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $selectation);

while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectationQuery))
{
   $return_arr[] = $data;    
}
```

echo json_encode($return_arr);
echo "Connected successfully";

?>
}

i think the code not reading the posted value at all

Answer (score 0):

The parameters don't look correct. You should try the following:

```
let paramString = "ID=1"
 to
let paramString: [String: Any] = [
                                 "ID" = "1"
                                  ]
```

use Alamofire, is an HTTP networking library it's easy. you can find
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

```
    let paramString:[String: Any] = [
                                      "ID" = 1
                                    ]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://mallsruh.com/mydata/test.php", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
        .responseJSON { request, response, JSON, error in
            print(response)
            print(JSON)
            print(error)
        }
```

Comment: it was support issue

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer support swift 5

```
AF.request("http://mallsruh.com/api/product/read_one.php", method: .get, parameters: ["id":a], encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: ["id":a]).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in
        switch response.result {
        case let .success(value):
            print(value)
        case let .failure(error):
            print(error)
```